# Richtige Übersetzung von Communication Skills im CV

Tags: translation

ich aktualisiere gerade meinen Lebenslauf und habe da eine tolle Vorlage eines Englischen CVs gefunden, dessen Stucktur ich gerne übernehmen möchte.

dort gibt es einen Punkt "Communication Skills" in dem der Autor seine Erfahrungen vor Publikum zu sprechen aufführt. Dieses würde ich gerne auch in meinen Deutschen Lebenslauf übernehmen.

Die direkte Übersetztung wäre ja "Kommunikative Fähigkeiten" was sich einersets für mich recht steif anhört und andererseits auch nicht den Kern dessen was unter diesem Punkt aufgeführt wird repräsentiert.

Ich suche also die Passende Übersetzung für "Kommunikative Fähigkeiten" im Kontext eines Lebenslaufes.

Comment: Einer der wichtigsten Punkte in einen Lebenslauf ist korrekte Rechtschreibung. Ich könnte zwar all deine Fehler in diesem Posting korrigieren, überlasse es aber lieber dir selbst das zu tun, denn bei deinem Lebenslauf wird dir auch niemand helfen.

Comment: Bei mir würde das vermutlich als Punkt/Überschrift „Kommunikation“ oder „Präsentation“ im Abschnitt „Fähigkeiten, Kenntnisse und Kompetenzen“ auftauchen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wenn es Dir auf Vortragen ankommt, könntest Du einen Punkt namens Reden, Vorträge oder Präsentationen machen und dann anfügen, was Du wo schon vorgetragen hast, z.B. so:

- Präsentationen: Vortrag über xyz bei Abc (Okt 2010), Keynote auf der Foobar-Konferenz (Apr 2011), regelmässiges Seminar zum Thema xyz bei Abc (Mai 2012 bis Jun 2015).

Meiner Meinung nach wäre das besser als ein schwammiges "Communication Skills" oder "Ausdrucksfähigkeit", weil Vortragen ein ganz anderes Kaliber ist als sich in Emails oder Meetings klar auszudrücken.

Answer (score 5):

Deutsche Übersetzungen etablierter englischer Fachbegriffe klingen tatsächlich oftmals steif. Das bedeutet aber nicht, dass sie falsch wären. Die Übersetzung

> Communication Skills = kommunikative Fähigkeiten

ist durchaus korrekt.

Aber weil sie eben holprig klingt, und weil der englische Fachbegriff auch unter deutschsprachigen HR-Managern gängig ist, ist eine häufig gewählte Alternative, diesen Fachbegriff nicht zu übersetzen:

> Communication Skills = Communication Skills

Etwas veraltet ist diese Umschreibung:

> Communication Skills = schriftliche und mündliche Ausdrucksfähigkeit

Ich fürchte aber, dass dieser Ausdruck noch steifer und holpriger klingt als »kommunikative Fähigkeiten«.

Kürzer wäre:

> Communication Skills = Ausdrucksfähigkeit

Aber unter die Ausdrucksfähigkeit fallen auch Mimik, Körpersprache und sogar Ausdruckstanz.

Viel wichtiger als die korrekte Übersetzung eines Fachbegriffs scheint mir aber zu sein, dass man seine kommunikativen Fähigkeiten unter Beweis stellt, indem man einen absolut fehlerfreien Lebenslauf abgibt.

Das heißt unter anderem:
Wörter am Anfang eines Satzes müssen mit einem Großbuchstaben beginnen, Adjektive hingegen werden kleingeschrieben (außer sie stehen am Anfang des Satzes) (passend, deutsch, englisch). Englische Anführungszeichen haben in einem deutschen Text nichts zu suchen, wohl aber Kommata an den richtigen Stellen. Die Schreibweise von Wörtern wie »Struktur« sollte man durch eine automatische Rechtschreibprüfung abklären, bevor man einen Text veröffentlicht.